# BIND with Dynamic DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, dynamic-dns

I'm using a DDNS service provider for my domain. Because my server is behind a router that changes IP.
I have just figure out that I can have a dns server (like BIND) inside my local server and, from what I read, (I need to have wildcard dns) I just have to submit this BIND NS record to the domain registar.
I would like to know if submiting my NS to the domain registar would work, even if my dns server (BIND for example) is behind a router that changes ip address from time to time.

Comment: Rent a VPS, host it on a VPS, or use a registrar that will act as a secondary to a server you run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's technically *possible* but *not recommended*. The main problem is that when the IP address changes it's unexpected, while it needs immediate actions. TTL for *glue records* is fixed and can't be lowered, while dynamic DNS records works because of extremely low TTL. Therefore, the `NS` pointing to DDNS hostname MUST be on a separate domain.

Another problem is that complying to IANA [Technical requirements for authoritative name servers](https://www.iana.org/help/nameserver-requirements) is impossible with a single server; *minimum number of name servers* and *network diversity*.

Comment: You mean that if my domain is example.com, I can't put in my domain registrar ns1.example.com? I need to use a different domain?

Comment: Yes, because that would be a *glue record*, and there's no DDNS for them.